# ASP.NET 3: What is a way to know what views and layouts are used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html

There are the following layouts and view:

_GlobalLayout.cshtml

_SubLoyout.cshtml

SomePage.cshtml

In the **_GlobalLayout.cshtml** I want to get a list of all used layouts and the current view name.

For example, in the **_GlobalLayout.cshtml**:

```
<html>
 <head>
   @Html.Some_method_that_will_know_about_used_layouts_and_view();
 </head>
 <body>
   @RenderBody();
 </body>
</html>
```

The **Some_method_that_will_know_about_used_layouts_and_view** will return some content using info about used layouts and used view.

How can I implement this method?

Comment: In the method I want to get a list like:

Comment: _GlobalLayout.cshtml
_SubLoyout.cshtml 
SomePage.cshtml

Comment: Unfortunately (and surprisingly), this appears to be impossible without reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of current view doesn't make sense. You haven't yet rendered the body (`@RenderBody()`) and expect to get a view name? You could get the current action and controller though from the `ViewContext`:

```
@{
    var currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
}
```

The main question remains though: why do you need this and what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: It does make sense.  The current view is the second one in the Output/Section stacks.  Also, its body already rendered (to `_tempWriter`)

Comment: That's merely a Razor implementation detail that we shouldn't be relying on when building an MVC application.

Comment: Q: why do you need this and what are you trying to achieve with it?
A: In my case, I am implementing a basic CMS where I need to load some page content in the final view and ideally implement this a couple of nested "master" templates so I know which template content to load. Is there no way of getting the parent layout names?

Answer (score 0):

You could set values in the PagesController:

```
Function YourPage() As ActionResult
    ViewData("NeedToLoadOtherTemplates") = True
    Return YourPage()
End Function
```

Then in your template view:

```
@If ViewData("NeedToLoadOtherTemplates") Then
    @loadTheOtherStuff
End If
```

You can add view data for every extra template you need.